# AngularJS: Show tooltip over the circle

Tags: angularjs, tooltip

I am writing code for show tooltop on mouseover. I need to display circular tooltip over the circle, when mouseover.

`Fiddle :`  http://jsfiddle.net/89RTg/77/

Here, tooltip is coming in the bottom of the cirlce. Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to put tooltip to center of circle, I modified your code, please review : 
`<http://jsfiddle.net/89RTg/80/>`

Comment: Thanks for reply. But, if there is multiple circles it won't work, it has to come dynamically.    [http://jsfiddle.net/89RTg/84/](http://jsfiddle.net/89RTg/84/)

Comment: If there is multiple circles, you need improve old code, please review  (http://jsfiddle.net/89RTg/85/)